# SQL filtering by time when it crosses midnight

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table of data like so:

```
RecordID    Gender  Age     TimeField
0015489     Male    85.0    2015-05-23 15:25:00.000
0015490     Male    95.0    2015-05-27 15:52:00.000
0015491     Male    66.0    2015-05-22 22:38:00.000
0015492     Male    60.0    2015-04-27 15:19:00.000
0015493     Male    83.0    2015-05-14 10:23:00.000
0015494     Male    78.0    2015-05-25 05:24:00.000
0015495     Male    80.0    2015-05-28 22:03:00.000
0015496     Male    81.0    2015-05-28 23:35:00.000
0015497     Male    91.0    2015-05-26 07:30:00.000
0015498     Male    88.0    2015-05-27 21:30:00.000
0015499     Male    76.0    2015-04-29 11:54:00.000
0015500     Male    76.0    2015-05-25 14:19:00.000
0015501     Male    84.0    2015-04-30 10:11:00.000
```

I only want to show records where the time element is between 16:36 and 07:58.

I can use the following select statement to filter on time:

```
select RecordId, Gender, Age, TimeField
from #testTime
where cast(Timefield as time) between '16:30' and '23:30'
```

but as soon as I try and use a time after midnight in the second part of the  between statement I get 0 results.

I'm presuming this is because midnight crosses over into a new date but I'm unsure how to reference that in my where clause.

Based on the sample table of data above I want the following output:

```
RecordID    Gender  Age     TimeField
0015491     Male    66.0    2015-05-22 22:38:00.000
0015494     Male    78.0    2015-05-25 05:24:00.000
0015495     Male    80.0    2015-05-28 22:03:00.000
0015496     Male    81.0    2015-05-28 23:35:00.000
0015497     Male    91.0    2015-05-26 07:30:00.000
0015498     Male    88.0    2015-05-27 21:30:00.000
```

What's the best way to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just make 2 criteria with or?

```
select RecordId, Gender, Age, TimeField
from #testTime
where (cast(Timefield as time) >= '16:30' or cast(Timefield as time) <= '03:00')
```

Comment: Thanks, in hindsight a fairly obvious solution!

Answer (score 3):

```
WHERE
    cast(Timefield as time) >= '16:36'
    OR cast(Timefield as time) <='07:58'
```

...should do it.

When you only look at the time component seperately, it's just like any monotonic numeric value from [Min] to [Max], it doesn't go around at it's peak.